# Checking For Single Value or Two or More Modes

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I'm trying to get my program to return a value without enclosing brackets if it is a single-mode; return the value as a list if it has two or more modes, and print out a message if there's no mode found in the given list.

```
def calculate_mode(numbers_list: list):

    frequency = {}

    mode = 0

    for num in numbers_list:
        frequency[num] = frequency.get(num, 0) + 1

    most_occurences = max(frequency.values())

    for key, value in frequency.items():
        if value == most_occurences:
            mode = key

    return mode


print(calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 17, 17]))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a single-digit mode return without the brackets. Using the unpackaging operator (*) will just remove modes that should be in a list. For example, [1] should be 1, but if I were to use the * operator, it would also change [1, 2] to 1 2. If there's no mode found in the given list, then it should just print out a message to the user.

A few examples:

```
>>> calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 17])
No Mode Found!

>>> calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 17, 17])
17

>>> calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 4, 17, 17])
[4, 17]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would return just a single mode (last one in the list) when multiple modes are present and last number in the list when no mode is present, since you have declared mode as an integer and are overwriting it in the for loop and for latter you don't have check if no modes are present.

My suggested answer to cover your test-cases is :

```
def calculate_mode(numbers_list: list):

    frequency = {}

    mode = []

    for num in numbers_list:
        frequency[num] = frequency.get(num, 0) + 1

    most_occurences = max(frequency.values())
    
    if most_occurences > 1: 
        for key, value in frequency.items():
            if value == most_occurences:
                mode.append(key)
    else:
        return('No Mode Found!')

    if len(mode)==1:
        return(mode[0])
    return mode

print(calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 17])) # Output: No Mode Found!
print(calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 17, 17])) # Output: 17
print(calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 4, 17, 17])) # Output: [4, 17]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def calculate_mode(numbers_list: list):
    frequency = {}
    mode = []

    for num in numbers_list:
        frequency[num] = frequency.get(num, 0) + 1
        
    most_occurences = max(frequency.values())
    
    mode = [key for key, value in frequency.items() if value == most_occurences]    
    
    
    if len(mode) == len(numbers_list):
        return 'No Mode Found!'
    elif len(mode)==1 :
        return mode[0]
    else:
        return mode

print(calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 17])) # Output: No Mode Found!
print(calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 17, 17])) # Output: 17
print(calculate_mode([10, 13, 5, 4, 4, 17, 17])) # Output: [4, 17]
```

output:

```
No Mode Found!
17
[4, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code return only one mode. i.e., the last mode. So whenever value matches the most_occurences, insert the key into a list and return the list.

Make the following changes in the code.

```
def calculate_mode(numbers_list: list):
    frequency = {}
    for num in numbers_list:
        frequency[num] = frequency.get(num, 0) + 1
    most_occurences = max(frequency.values())
    return [key for key, value in frequency.items() if value == most_occurences]
```